# Django memcache performance monitoring

Tags: django, memcached

I'm using memcache in my django site to cache db reads and API data. I have a dedicated server running for memcache. Now i want to measure the performance of using memcache (hits and misses from the cache). I'm using django 1.3 and python 2.4. Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tooting my own horn here, but this django module was made for showing memcache status and performing basic admin functions. It can be used in production with no performance penalty.

https://github.com/ianare/django-memcache-admin

Answer (score 3):

The [Django debug toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) has [a plugin](https://github.com/ross/memcache-debug-panel) that gives you cache statistics.

Comment: Thanks.can i use it in production server? will it slow down my application?

Answer (score 1):

```
echo stats | nc cache_server_address 11211
```

Comment: print out statistics, surprisingly enough - try it, it's safe

Comment: i m just curious can u give a example output... have to wait for a day to try it